# Chrome is acting strange

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, frontend

I have a strange problem, I can't really write down all the code because it's long but basically it looks like this.

A made a menu on a website and it works great, and looks great in every browser to except chrome. I know that's strange because usually chrome is the best.

http://konyvelespecs.com/

So please check the page in Mozilla or Opera or IE, the top navigation should look ok, but check it in chrome and it should break but the weird thing is that it only happens the first time you view the page; after a refresh it is ok. However, if you close the browser window and load it again, the problem shows again until a new refresh.

I'm all out of ideas - does anybody know why this is happening?

So here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Didn't break for me on Chrome.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu what version of Chrome do you have ? Because i all ready check'd it on a few different desktops and versions and its not working

Comment: Works fine for me on 26.0.1410.64

Comment: Same as Alex -------------^^. Clear cache. I can't think of much else being wrong.

Comment: flagged as too localized.

Comment: Same for me - looks ok in Chrome

Comment: Same as Alex Lynham and DarkCthulhu for me...

Comment: But how i dont understand, i cleared everything i checked it on 4 more different comeputers i just dont understand. Anyways thank you all for the answers

Comment: But are you saying that the top nav is not a bit broken?

Comment: could you attach a screenshot of what 'broken' mean? bc i dont know what to look for.

Comment: @Vprimachenko ok, one sec.

Comment: @Vprimachenko updated it whit a screenshot

Comment: can't reproduce, maybe check your font stack

Comment: I have it to on my old desktop
//EDIT//
Seems to be fixed?

Comment: @DiederikEEn you just probably refreshed the page, Try reloading it in a new windows

Comment: @Mr.Sam Add position:absolute;

Comment: @DiederikEEn thank you it seems like it resolved it

Comment: @Mr.Sam I added it as awnser ;) easyer for people to find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `position:absolute` :)

Comment: This was already mentioned in a comment.

Comment: umm yes my comment.. Just did this so it would be easyer to find..